# Is it best practice to have mail sent from the root domain when the service is accessed via a subdomain name?

Tags: email, web, best-practices

Running an outward facing server for contractors who's hostname is sub.example.com. The service needs to send mail to the contractors for various reasons (new projects, login details, etc). I have no intentions on making this machine an smtp server, and can successfully send mail through smtp.gmail.com, as I have [Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en).

Trouble is, the emails go out as account@example.com, where  is the account I use to authenticate to smtp.google.com to send the mail, when I'd like it to go out as differentaccount@sub.example.com.

I supposed that could be looked upon as spoofing in a way, so I understand why this wouldn't readily be done.

Setting up sendmail with an smtp relay worked, but all the emails end up in junk folders during my test. This continued even after I setup SPF records for the subdomain on the root domain's dns.

It would be a lot of effort to setup and administer an smtp server just for this, as the mail volume won't be that serious. I can settle for sending mail from the root domain account through smtp.gmail if it's good practice (I can't remember if I've come across this before as a customer/user, even if I have that wouldn't mean it's good practice).

Which brings me to my question, albeit I've tried to remove any subjectiveness: Is it best practice to send the email with the matching domain as the service (admin@sub.example.com), or is sending from the root domain (admin@example.com) just as acceptable?

Comment: There is no "best practice" here - do whatever you want subject to other spam control measures.

Comment: @voretaq7 *no one cares as long as the email gets there*, right? I thought about that, thanks for confirming. Comment too short to be an answer?

Comment: It's really too subjective/provider-dependent to answer. Someone **could** theoretically assign a higher spam score for subdomains, there's just no valid reason I can think of to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due largely to voretaq's input, I've decided to send the email from support@example.com, the root domain.
The main reason for this is that no one really cares where the email comes from, as long as it arrives.